# edit css primeNG dataTable header

Tags: angular, datatable, background-color, primeng

Hye everyone, I am currently devloping a user interface using angular 2 and primeNG components.

I use dataTable (p-dataTable) component and I would like to change the background color of the dataTable header.

I tried to edit .ui-datatable-header and .ui-datatable-thead classes but nothing worked.

If you have a solution, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following:

```
.ui-datatable .ui-datatable-thead > tr > th {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: The dataTable header always has the default background color :( thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Jordy This code works 100%. Add CSS I provided to this plnkr's CSS file for example and you'll see it works: https://embed.plnkr.co/d9hQLeW3r95SMtCioTqt/

Comment: You were right, I added the css in the wrong file, this morning I put it in style.css and it works. Thank you so much!!!!! :D

Comment: sorry to burst in but how to i add it to some columns, i've used styleClass="switchTable" on the columns i want but cant seem to get them